# d3 line graph does not present data correctly when called again

Tags: json, graph, d3.js

I'm trying to graph the x,y,z values from an accelerometer reading on a phone using the d3 line graph code below.  The first measurement works great for graphing.  Subsequent measurements though produce an odd graph where each value is a flat line & then compressed like it's at a very high frequency at the end.  However if I reset the app & run it again the graph is fine.  When I export the data and look at in a spreadsheet it appears to be giving valid (ie. changing x,y,z& time values).  I've thought it might be a speed issue & have reduced the measurement time to even 1000ms, but the problem continues.  It seems a variable is not being reset after it creates the first graph.

I'm storing the accelerometer data in json format in local storage with the measurement time as the key.  To get a graph I use the key (which is stored in a div id to get the correct json file from local storage & then convert it to an array for the d3 setup to read.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
function graph() {

    var key = $("#graph_info").text();

    var dataObject = window.localStorage.getItem(key);

    var data = JSON.parse(dataObject);


    data = $.map(data, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});

    // set up a colour variable
    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    // map one colour each to x, y and z
    // keys grabs the key value or heading of each key value pair in the json
    // but not time
//    console.log(d3.keys(data[0]));
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
        return key !== "timestamp";
    }));

    // create a nested series for passing to the line generator
    // it's best understood by console logging the data
    var series = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
            name: name,
            values: data.map(function(d) {
                return {
                    timestamp: d.timestamp,
                    score: +d[name]
                };
            })
        };
    });

    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {
        top: 40,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 35,
        left: 30
    },
        width = 260 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 220 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//        height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);

    // Define the line
    // Note you plot the time / score pair from each key you created ealier 
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
            return x(d.timestamp);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return y(d.score);
        });


    // Adds the svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("#graph")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.timestamp;
    }));

    // note the nested nature of this you need to dig an additional level
    y.domain([
        d3.min(series, function(c) {
            return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
                return v.score;
            });
        }),
        d3.max(series, function(c) {
            return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
                return v.score;
            });
        })
    ]);

    // create a variable called series and bind the date
    // for each series append a g element and class it as series for css styling
    var series = svg.selectAll(".series")
        .data(series)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "series");

    // create the path for each series in the variable series i.e. x, y and z
    // pass each object called x, y nad z to the lne generator
    series.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
 //           console.log(d); // to see how d3 iterates through series
            return valueline(d.values);
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return color(d.name);
        });

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
    .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
    .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    //top title message
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))             
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
        .style("font-size", "16px")  
        .text(key);

    //Lower X-Axis title
    svg.append("text")      // text label for the x axis
        .attr("x", width / 2 )
        .attr("y",  height + margin.bottom)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Seconds from measurement");

    svg = "";
    key = "";
    dataObject = "";
    data = [];

};

function showCurrentGraph() {
    graph(); 


}    



// End graphing code
```

Comment: Your selection is named like your data array, besides, the attributes of the elements are being set on enter only. See the answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are naming your selection with the same name than your data:

```
// Use another name for the selection
var series = svg.selectAll(".series")
    .data(series)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "series");
```

Also, the problem is that you are assigning the attributes to your elements on enter only, not updating them. For instance, using only the series groups, your code should look more like this:

```
// Create the selection and bind the data
var series = svg.selectAll("g.series").data(data);

// Append elements on enter (make sure to add the class at this point)
series.enter().append("g").attr("class", "series");

// Update the attributes of the series (transform in this case)
series.attr('transform', function(d, i) { return 'translate(' + i + ', 0)'; });

// Remove the lines on exit.
series.exit().remove();
```

I strongly recommend reading the following articles by Mike Bostock: [How selections work](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/), [Nested Selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) and [Towards Reusable charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/). Regards,

Comment: Hi Pablo,  Thanks so much for your information.  I entered the above example ie:

Comment: Hi Pablo,  Thanks so much for your information.  Would you mind possibly pondering a challenge I'm having with this change?  I entered the above example (from the second code area) but am now getting an error message saying " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined "  When I use:  var series = svg.selectAll("g.series").data(series) ... I don't get the error.  I'll try to track down why data is undefined there & also read the references you sent -- I greatly appreciate it ;)

Comment: Ok, I think I'm making a newbie mistake here as adding .data(data[0]) stops the error, but provides a blank graph.  I'm guessing there is a range value for the array?  Sorry if this is painfully obvious for everyone, I'm still getting used to d3.  Thanks

Comment: Can you share the structure of the `data` variable? I think that the binding is not being made correctly.

Comment: I'm reading the accelerometer data & "pushing" it to an array, then converting the array to json w/ a timestamp as the key for local storage.  I'm having issues getting the console to print the array format.  However the json files (minus the timestamp look like:  [{"x":0.4405331015586853,"y":-0.3256114423274994,"z":10.017339706420898,"timestamp":1404306774439}, ... ] The json file is converted back to an array that should be of a similar format (ie. x,y,z,timestamp) but I'm new to Javascript & am fumbling around ;)

Comment: unfortunately when do a console.log(data.toString()); it returns an array of objects but not the actual data, I'll try to see what I'm missing & post it -- thanks

Comment: What about `console.log(data)`?

Comment: console.log(data);  shows on the console: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],....

Comment: I'll try to use some print function to see what is in the array, Thanks

Comment: I see, you actually have a data array called `series`. Can you rename the group selection then? Replace `var series = svg.selectAll(".series").data(series)...` by `var grpSeries = svg.selectAll(".series").data(series)...` and then all the instances where you use `series` as a selection.

Comment: Hi Pablo, I really appreciate your help by the way.  I made those changes of changing things to grpSeries (plus adding the above corrections you mentioned) & the graphs display.  However unfortunately it still only shows the first graph correctly after taking measurements.  If I reset the emulator or stop/start the test app on my phone it takes graphs correctly for the first (new) measurement.  However if I export the data & graph it in a spread sheet, all data sets are ok.  Here's a link to a photo:  http://i61.tinypic.com/2nrhaus.png  Thanks so much if you have any other thoughts on this ;)

Comment: Please, mark the question as answered if you considered the problem solved, and consider creating a new question for the last issue. Glad to help!

Comment: Hi Pablo -- Thanks again for your help!  I discovered that the cause of the weird graphs was due to the first 1-3 measurements having odd timestamps.  I'm guessing pushing the measurement rate below 20ms/reading is hitting the upper limit of what javascript & the phone clock speed can handle.  Dropping the first 5 measurements on each test fixed it.  This didn't show up in the other graphing tool I was using because it was already doing noise correction & likely dropped those points.  So your suggestions were correct -- the error was in my data.  Have a great weekend!